# WebVR on GearVR is very pixelated

Tags: webgl, webvr

I'm working on some WebVR research, I've managed to rotate some cubes with textures and using the correct projection/view matrices provided by webvr running it on the GearVR (with a s7 edge).

The results are very pixelated. The oculus menu/apps aren't. It seems it is falling back on a lowres. Is there any settings to increase the quality or change the resolution?

Comment: I've seen a parameter on the `requestPresent` which is `framebufferScaleFactor`, but didn't take any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this:

By requesting the renderWidth/renderHeight for each eye, you can resize your canvas to the highest size for best results.

For example:

```
var leftEye = display.getEyeParameters('left');
var rightEye = display.getEyeParameters('right');

canvas.width = Math.max(leftEye.renderWidth, rightEye.renderWidth) * 2;
canvas.height = Math.max(leftEye.renderHeight, rightEye.renderHeight);
```